# How to convert this .txt data into a list of points

Tags: import, string-manipulation

## Question

How to import data from a .txt file into *Mathematica* and convert it to an expression?

Download the .txt file here (click download):

http://pastebin.com/2NW2DfiE

Comment: Why are you doing `ImportString[]` after `Import[]`? Try importing it as `"CSV"` instead.

Comment: This is because for instance `{"6.1101,17.592"}` isn't a valid expression. You could either manipulate the strings to split them into something like `{"6.1101","17.592"}` and then use `ToExpression`. Or you could use `SemanticImportString`. This allows you to convert to whatever kind of expression you want (such as real numbers) and split strings at `,` at the same time

Answer (score 1):

solution 1

```
Import["/Users/johncosnett/Downloads/xydata.txt", "CSV"]
```

[image]

---

solution 2

```
SemanticImportString[
   Import["/Users/johncosnett/Downloads/xydata.txt"]]
```

[image]

---

[image]